# restrict coupon codes for only one time use in magento 1.9.0

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon-codes

[image]For orders above 200, we are giving free shipping on our site.

We would also like to have a "Free Shipping " coupon code applicable to orders below 200

I gave Uses per Coupon : 1 , Uses per Customer : 1

(see attached image) but still for registered customers also, can use coupon codes many times and buy the product.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Does solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply that rules to guest  user, you need to also select `NOT LOGGED IN` at  Customer group multiple options.

Magento counts this as guest customer.

**Uses per Coupon**

The number of times the coupon code can be used.

`Uses per Customer`

Determines how `many times the coupon code can be used by the same registered customer` who belongs to `any` of the `selected customer groups`. The setting does not apply to guest shoppers who are members of the `NOT LOGGED IN` customer group, or `to customers who shop without logging in to their accounts. If there is no limit, leave the field blank`.

See at [here](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#marketing/price-rules-shopping-cart.html%3FTocPath%3DMarketing%2520%7CPromotions%7CShopping%2520Cart%2520Price%2520Rules%7C_____0)